Inconsistency in subtracting area of unit square with unit circle for pi approximate calculation using Monte Carlo simulation
I have run into problems involving the fact that areas cannot be subtracted or it will lead to contradiction and inconsistency. Area division leads to no issues in $\pi = 3.14$. Can you help me see where I went wrong in such a basic calculation?
Problem: $4$ sq. units $- \pi$ sq. units is giving incorrect value on simulation.

First 10 decimal digits of pi are
$\pi = 3.1415926535 $

I was estimating the value of pi using Monte Carlo simulation of unit circle in unit square so this is a common technique.



Imagine a unit cirle at (0, 0) origin of radius 1 unit.

Image a unit square centered at origin of side length 2. The unit circle is completely inside the square touching it at 4
points(midsections of the square sides).

The area of the square is 4 sq. units.

The area of the circle is $\pi$ sq. units.

Subtracting the area of square - circle gives $4 - \pi$ sq. units which is $\approx 0.8584$ sq. units.

Dividing the area we get $\frac{\pi}{4} =$ Area of $\frac{circle}{square}$



Here is the result of the Monte Carlo simulation on a computer(python code provided for copy-paste verification)

N=1_000_000 Threw 1_000_000 darts at the unit square. 1 million random points (x,y) where $x,y 
\in [-1, 1]$

K=785_490 785_490 darts fell inside unit circle. Calculated by point distance (x,y) to origin <= 1 using $a^2 + b^2 <= 1$.

Ratio of $ = \frac{\pi}{4}$ calculated was 0.785490 which yields $\pi = 3.14$ when multiplied by 4, through dividing the areas correctly. Here is the calculation
$\frac{K}{N} = \frac{785,490}{1,000,000} = 0.785490$. So the number K/N converges on is $\approx 0.7854$. The first two digits are precise, increasing N to $\infty$ will converge the further decimal places.

If I multiply 0.785490 x 4 $\approx$ 3.14. Thus division of area point no 6. gives a better and better estimate of $\pi$.


Now the problematic part - Subtracting the areas

If I subtract the areas, $4 - \pi$ converges on $\approx 0.8584$ sq. units on paper. This 0.85 is a problem.
Points cannot be treated as areas? If every point has $\Delta$ radius $\Delta \approx 0$, then $4 - \pi = \frac{N}{N} - \frac{K}{N}$
This gives us $0.8584 \approx 0.7854$ contradiction.
If it is said N is not large enough to be $\infty$ to cover all the points, it is not valid as increasing N only converges both values to 0.85 sq. units and 0.78 sq. units further.
Something stole/ate/owned 0.07 sq. units of area. Was it other transcendental numbers on the area graph? Was it fractals? Was it some numbers around the origin (0, 0)? Was it the points around the circle or square border? Is there a hidden multiplication coefficient here? Do all random points not have equal area or is there a secret bias/preference for certain points in area? Or is it just an error due to equating $4 - \pi$ to a point-based area approximate?
Why can't I blot out the 4 sq. units of area with an infinite number of point areas? If it was an error to infinity, why are the values converging even more strongly on the 0.07 sq. units error on increasing points?
If I was to rearrange the equation $4 - \pi = \frac{N}{N} - \frac{K}{N}$ which gives
$4 - \pi = 1 - \frac{K}{N}$ which simplifies to
$3 + \frac{K}{N} = \pi $
Calculating/Approximating $\pi$ in this way gives converging value $\pi = 3.78$. Is this a mistake? Or does $\pi$ have an alternate value of 3.78?

Here is the Copy-paste Monte Carlo Unit Circle Simulation for calculating pi for verification
monte_carlo_piapprox.py
import numpy as np
import math

n = 1_000_000

position_x = [x*2 - 1  for x in list(np.random.rand(1, n))[0]]
position_y = [x*2 - 1 for x in list(np.random.rand(1, n))[0]]

def distance_origin(x, y):
  return x**2 + y**2

def is_inside_unit_circle(x, y):
  distance = distance_origin(x, y)
  return distance <= 1

def monte_carlo_pythagoras_pi(x, y):
  points_inside = len([1 for i in range(n) if is_inside_unit_circle(position_x[i], position_y[i])])
  k = points_inside
  ratio = k/n
  return [4*ratio, 3 + k/n, k]

[pi_area_division, pi_area_subtraction, points_inside] = monte_carlo_pythagoras_pi(position_x, position_y)
k = points_inside

print("PI approximation calculated:")
print(pi_area_division)
print("\nPoints inside unit circle:")
print(points_inside)
print("\nTotal points inside unit square:")
print(n)
print("\nK/N ratio(pi/4):")
print(k/n)
print("\nError in area on subtract:")
print((4 - pi_area_division) - (k/n) )
print("\nPI consistency error in area subtraction:")
print(pi_area_subtraction)
print("\nPI expected: 3.141592")

Output:
PI approximation calculated:
3.143512

Points inside unit circle:
785878

Total points inside unit square:
1000000

K/N ratio(pi/4):
0.785878

Error in area on subtract:
0.07

PI consistency error in area subtraction:
3.785878

PI expected: 3.141592

Additional problems I am looking closer into due to $\pi$ definition

Pi as a rational number through $\zeta(\infty)$ aka Zeta(Infinity).
The definition of $\pi$ at $\zeta(\infty)$ is


$\pi = (1 + \frac{1}{2^\infty} + \frac{1}{3^\infty} + ...$ to $\infty$) $. \frac{p}{q}$ where p, q belong to Natural numbers. $pi$ is very much irrational, but at approaching infinity or limits of our understanding around the true definition of pi the irrationality of pi dies out. For example if there were the slightest quantization similar to how light is continuous but discrete at very small values photons behave as particles transferring a fixed quanta of energy, pi would ignore the $+ \frac{1}{2^\infty}$ and become rational number. Transcendental numbers appear in lot of places that have nothing to do with pi or trigonometry.


$\sqrt{2}$ as a very long rational number. Most definitions of Sqrt 2 define the number 2. By modifying the definition of 2, or forbidding it in proof of sqrt 2 being proven irrational for avoiding circular reasoning. Sqrt 2 might point to a very large Natural number, the square of which is 2.0000..., which for all intents it is simply easier to call sqrt 2 as irrational and define the number 2 incorrectly(if sqrt 2 was a rational between 1 and 2). Sqrt 2 might be a rational number much bigger than humans can comprehend, so we keep making more rigorous proofs that get disproved( or tautology in circles) around proving irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$. What difference does it make if a number is rational? It plays a role in substitution, definition and positioning on the number line. But if it is irrational, these 3 things become more complicated. If at some point $\sqrt{2}$ starts giving an infinite number of decimal zeros, then the information given by sqrt 2 would be finite, instead of infinite, just big enough finite to never be written down. Plus checking the decimal expansion of sqrt 2 for any recurring subsets of arbitrary length will give the best computers a marathon of calculations.

I was reading the history of pythagoras and the irrational numbers heresy and it has created more questions about the proof of irrational numbers which I used to consider trivial textbook irrational number proof.
Edit: The mistake looks pretty obvious in hindsight.
$N-K$ is valid only as
$4 - \pi = N.\Delta - K.\Delta$
when subtracting area without using any division or ratio.
$\frac{N - K}{N}$ can only be used when normalizing $4 - \pi$ by the total area 4 sq. units.
I took the normalization factor to be 1 incorrectly after looking at the unit circle of radius 1, so I incorrectly divided by N.
I would have spotted it if I visualized it correctly, since it is Monte-Carlo I tried to do all the calculations with matrix.
$\frac{N-K}{N} = \frac{4 - \pi}{4}$ is the correct starting point.
$4 - \pi = (1 - \frac{K}{N}).4$ and $\pi = 4.\frac{K}{N}$

I don't understand what are you trying to do with area subtraction... Forget about pi, let's say you have points in the square. Without looking at the value of the drawn points (to estimate the square side) there's no way to estimate the area of the square just by knowing how many points have been drawn. Aren't you trying to do the same thing here?

Like $N/N -K/N$ is going to tend towards $1-\pi/4$ which is not the area difference...

yes you're correct, $1 - \pi/4$ is not the area difference. But it should be the area difference if I blot out the entire square with all the points that exist inside the unit square. In short we lost 7% of the area in a unit square due to a contradiction we don't understand. N points in a unit square represents all the points in the unit square. K points represents all the points in a unit circle. Yet the values tending towards infinity are not converging showing we neglected a 7% area on the number line to the void. (N - K)/N semantically represents $4 - \pi$ sq. units of area.

The contradiction I have raised is $4 - \pi = \frac{\pi}{4}$. It is easy to see the contradiction, but why are they not equal? Semantically they are the same and there is proof for both LHS and RHS and the equality. Yet numerically it does not add up and never will as it shows $\pi = \frac{16}{5}$ which is exactly equal to 3.2 not approximately equal. But we also know $\pi$ is exactly equal to 3.1415. My understanding is there is a problem with our math in subtracting areas from each other, especially when circular areas are involved.

Link for reference to a standard Monte Carlo estimation of Pi Monte Carlo Pi Approximation

Turns out, it was indeed a small problem in the pi simulation calculations by a normalization factor of 4. That increased the error in pi calculation on subtracting areas by 400%.

The problem is in you writing $$4-\pi\approx\color{red}{\frac{N}{N}-\frac{K}{N}}$$
Let us do the calculations formally. You are throwing a dart in the square uniformly at random. Then $$\mathbb P(\text{dart lands in circle})=\frac{\text{Area of circle}}{\text{Area of square}}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$ From your simulations, the empirical probability $\hat{\mathbb P}(\text{dart lands in circle})$ is $$\hat{\mathbb P}(\text{dart lands in circle})=\frac{K}{N}$$
Equating these two observations (as an approximation) gives you an approximation for $\pi$. Well and good.

Now, what is the probability that the dart lands outside the circle is $$\mathbb P(\text{dart lands outside circle})=\frac{\text{Area outside circle}}{\text{Area of square}}=\frac{4-\pi}{4}$$
Empirically, you have $$\hat{\mathbb P}(\text{dart lands outside circle})=\frac{N-K}{N}$$
Again equating them as approximations, we get $$4-\pi\approx\frac{4(N-K)}{N}$$
Adding a line to your code at the end does give the correct value of $4-\pi\approx 0.85$


Ah I see my mistake now, thank you. I took $4 - \pi$ but I did not normalise it by 4. So the correct normalization would have been $\frac{4 - \pi}{4}$

Yes, that is right.
